# Query from property file in mongo db in spring boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Is it possible to read mongo db query from property file in spring boot application.

I have property file where I need to keep my all query and read the same in repository. I am able to read the data for findItemByName, I am not able do for the mongodb propagation.

Any way to read the data from property file for mongo db propagation.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<GroceryItem, String> {
@Query(value = "GroceryItem.findItemByName")  --->Working
GroceryItem findItemByName(String name);

//@Query(value = "{category:'?0'}", fields = "{'name' : 1, 'quantity' : 1}")
@Query(value = "GroceryItem.findAll", fields="GroceryItem.findAlls")  --> Not working
List<GroceryItem> findAll(String category);

public long count();
```

}

Comment: Should you not use MongoRepository if you are using mongoDb ?

Comment: Yes I can use. I am trying to build a common sdk for all Nosql database. Right now I am trying to have CRUD repository. But my problem is different. How can I have read query from property file?